# HTML clickable div query

Tags: html, css

I am using divs to act as buttons so I can style them more easily how I want them.

I also have a fixed banner at the top of the screen using 'position:fixed;'

Now I've done this everything goes to the top of the screen and ignores the banner so when I click a button to scroll to the section of the site it goes under the banner rather than underneath.

How can I shunt it all down slightly to stop them overlapping?

Comment: Need to see your code

Comment: All of it or just sections cause I'm unsure which sections it would be

Comment: Have you overall header in `postition:fixed` wrap all of that stuffed their. Then have a main container div and margin it off by the height of the div.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/a4kbxtqL/

Answer (score 0):

```
ul#menu li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could just use a button, and style it with

```
button {background-color: white;border: none;}
```

and it looks like a div with a white background.